# Chart.js not showing/skipping labels

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, chart.js

I'm currently working on a dashboard and im trying to display a score across a lot of people.

Here is my chart.js code.

```
<script>
                            const labels = [
                                @foreach($all_staff as $staff)
                                    @php
                                    $i++;
                                    @endphp
                                '{{ $i }}',
                                @endforeach
                            ];
                            const data = {
                                labels: labels,
                                datasets: [{
                                    label: 'My First dataset',
                                    backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                                    borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                                    data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 50],
                                }]

                            };
                            // </block:setup>

                            // <block:config:0>
                            const config = {
                                type: 'bar',
                                data,
                                options: {indexAxis: 'y',
                                    scaleShowValues: true,
                                    scales: {
                                        xAxes: [{
                                            ticks: {
                                                beginAtZero: true
                                            }
                                        }],
                                        yAxes: [{
                                            stacked: false,
                                            ticks: {
                                                autoSkip: false,
                                                beginAtZero: true,
                                                stepSize: 1,
                                            }
                                        }]
                                    }
                                }
                            };
                            // </block:config>

                            // === include 'setup' then 'config' above ===

                            var myChart = new Chart(
                                document.getElementById('myChart'),
                                config
                            );
                        </script>
```

Now like the title says its not showing all the labels:
[my chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSCWc.png)

so I have tried the fixes from here: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2801

sadly none of those worked.

Any help would be great! thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

You're `x` and `y` axis configurations are wrong, they should be objects instead of arrays.

If you do it like this it should work:

```js
options: {
  scales: {
    x: {
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    },
    y: {
      ticks: {
        autoSkip: false,
        beginAtZero: true,
        stepSize: 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```